# Can I pass date to the method scheduleAtFixedRate using class Timer?

Tags: java, timer

I've read a lot of answers about using Timer. I'm trying to understand how to pass date (or I can't?) to the method [scheduleAtFixedRate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.util.TimerTask-java.util.Date-long-) which has two forms:

1) `void sheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)`

2) `void scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, Date firstTime, long period)` (I mean this form now)

And I'm using 2nd form like:

```
//creating a new instance of timer class
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new Helper();

        Date date = new Date();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, date, 5000);
```

Where `date` used without any specified values. But can I specify date, in this example? Correct me, if I'm wrong, please.

Comment: what do you meant by "Where date used without any specified values" you are passing the date from when you need to start this, which is what you want right?

Comment: I mean, can I specify date, when this method will be executed or no?

Comment: @GhostCat, thanks for ur help! Your answer was helpful, but I thought about [class Timer not Interface ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.util.TimerTask-java.util.Date-long-) or here is the same logic?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you got confused by the javadoc.

There is only *one* reason to use `Date` related code:

> All schedule methods accept relative delays and periods as arguments, not absolute times or dates. It is a simple matter to transform an absolute time represented as a Date to the required form. For example, to schedule at a certain future date, you can use: schedule(task, date.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).

In other words: when you intend to *setup* a Date object to represent the 1st of August 2018, and you want your code to run at *that* day, then you could do so using the above code.

In other words: you use Date arithmetic to **compute** the **delay** required to have the task start at a specific date/time.

Just to be really clear: your own code example from the question ( `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, date, 5000);`), this code is invalid!

There is **no** method in that class that takes a **Date** object directly. All methods only accept long values, representing an initial **delay**!

Comment: just updated my question -https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.util.TimerTask-java.util.Date-long- . I thought about class Timer not Interface ScheduledExecutorService